# Getting chunk colour of ProgressBar

Tags: qt, progress-bar

I have problems getting colour of progress bar's chunk and have found nothing in documentation.

For example:

`progBar->palette().color(QWidget::foregroundRole())` gives me foreground colour but what about chunk?

So, how can I get the colour of progress bar's chunk if I had no style sheets installed for it?
Is there any solution with palettes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some tests I find solution. The colour of QProgressBar chunk is palette's Highlight role, so code is going to be like:
`progBar->palette().color(QPalette::Highlight);`